# Is there an open source implementation of QGM (Query Graph Model)?

Tags: postgresql, hive, apache-spark

I am building a new system that needs to interact essentially as an SQL backend.  We would like to import logical queries into it (e.g. from ApacheSPARQ or Postgres and related things) and want to develop an internal representation (IR) for them.  Doing something similar to QGM seems like a good starting point.  However, rather than inventing it all from scratch, I'd like to borrow from something that already exists and then extend as needed.

Even if there is no processing code, just data structures, it would be a useful starting point.

So, if there is something open source that I could look at, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could take a look at AGE ([A Graph Extension](https://github.com/apache/incubator-age)) - an Open Source graph extension based on PostgreSQL...

Comment: It looks interesting.  I'm not sure it is what I am looking for now, but it might be useful in the long run.